# Can't compile XPages project on HCL Designer 12.0.1. FP1

Tags: xpages, hcl, hcl-notes

I have recently migrated my old XPages application to HCL Domino 12. I have also upgraded my dev environment to the same version. Unfortunately I am not able to compile the project since then. The process got stuck when it tries to invoke XSP builder as shown in the picture. Has anybody same/similar experience?

[image]

Google search did not show anything related.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the picture :-)

Comment: Picture added .. I am really a newbie ;)

Comment: is the project connected to source control ?

Comment: No it is not connected to any source control

Comment: I have tried to instal HCL Domino Designer 12.0.2 on a different computer but the results are the same .. the compile process gets stuck

Comment: @MirekNavratil I've not seen a hang as I've moved to 12.0.2.  IF you are using external libraries like the OpenNTF Domino API upgrading often disables them.  You should go into Application Management to re-enable them but again I've not seen this symptom at all.  Are you using the 64bit version?  I've only used the 32bit so far.

Comment: have you tried "clean and build the project" to remove the error?